# Jhipster project, Angular select dropdown, how to call function to load more data as options

Tags: angular, jhipster

In my Jhipster project, I have two entities, a User entity and a UserProfile entity. They have a OneToOne relationship. This would mean for every userProfile created, I must be able to link a user when creating or updating a userprofile.

The issue I see is that, when the page to create a user profile opens, a GET API call `/api/users` returns a fixed size of the first 20 users. This is an issue when we have over 20 users and cannot link the other users to any user profiles. The 21st user ID is never seen in the dropdown list. This scenario is highlighted in the two images below.

//21st User created
[21st User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBmrS.png)

// Create or Update userprofile
[The drop down to link a user to userprofile does not give the 21user as an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZcTP.png)

I would like to keep the scroll, instead of displaying a long dropdown list. But how can I keep adding the next users in this case?

The versions I am using are

- Jhipster version : 7.9.3
- Angular version : 14.2.1

I am pretty new to angular so I'm not sure how to go about it.

---

This is the UserProfile.json I have

```
{
  "changelogDate": "20230822202636",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "telephone",
      "fieldType": "String",
      "fieldValidateRules": ["required"]
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "address",
      "fieldType": "String"
    }
  ],
  "name": "UserProfile",
  "pagination": "pagination",
  "readOnly": false,
  "relationships": [
    {
      "id": true,
      "otherEntityField": "login",
      "otherEntityName": "user",
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "userProfile",
      "ownerSide": true,
      "relationshipName": "user",
      "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
      "relationshipValidateRules": ["required"]
    }
  ],
  "service": "no"
}
```

---

// user-profile-update-componenet.html - the form with the dropdown that list the different users as options

```
<div class="row mb-3">
          <label class="form-label" for="field_user">User</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="field_user" data-cy="user" name="user" formControlName="user" [compareWith]="compareUser">
            <option *ngIf="!editForm.get('user')!.value" [ngValue]="null" selected></option>
            <option [ngValue]="userOption" *ngFor="let userOption of usersSharedCollection">{{ userOption.login }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="editForm.get(['user'])!.invalid && (editForm.get(['user'])!.dirty || editForm.get(['user'])!.touched)">
          <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="editForm.get(['user'])?.errors?.required"> This field is required. </small>
        </div>
      </div>
```

---

// user-profile-update-component.ts - the loadRelationshipsOptions() method loads the users initially

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { UserProfileFormService, UserProfileFormGroup } from './user-profile-form.service';
import { IUserProfile } from '../user-profile.model';
import { UserProfileService } from '../service/user-profile.service';
import { IUser } from 'app/entities/user/user.model';
import { UserService } from 'app/entities/user/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-user-profile-update',
  templateUrl: './user-profile-update.component.html',
})
export class UserProfileUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  isSaving = false;
  userProfile: IUserProfile | null = null;

  usersSharedCollection: IUser[] = [];

  editForm: UserProfileFormGroup = this.userProfileFormService.createUserProfileFormGroup();

  constructor(
    protected userProfileService: UserProfileService,
    protected userProfileFormService: UserProfileFormService,
    protected userService: UserService,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  compareUser = (o1: IUser | null, o2: IUser | null): boolean => this.userService.compareUser(o1, o2);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ userProfile }) => {
      this.userProfile = userProfile;
      if (userProfile) {
        this.updateForm(userProfile);
      }

      this.loadRelationshipsOptions();
    });
  }

  previousState(): void {
    window.history.back();
  }

  save(): void {
    this.isSaving = true;
    const userProfile = this.userProfileFormService.getUserProfile(this.editForm);
    if (userProfile.id !== null) {
      this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.userProfileService.update(userProfile));
    } else {
      this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.userProfileService.create(userProfile));
    }
  }

  protected subscribeToSaveResponse(result: Observable<HttpResponse<IUserProfile>>): void {
    result.pipe(finalize(() => this.onSaveFinalize())).subscribe({
      next: () => this.onSaveSuccess(),
      error: () => this.onSaveError(),
    });
  }

  protected onSaveSuccess(): void {
    this.previousState();
  }

  protected onSaveError(): void {
    // Api for inheritance.
  }

  protected onSaveFinalize(): void {
    this.isSaving = false;
  }

  protected updateForm(userProfile: IUserProfile): void {
    this.userProfile = userProfile;
    this.userProfileFormService.resetForm(this.editForm, userProfile);

    this.usersSharedCollection = this.userService.addUserToCollectionIfMissing<IUser>(this.usersSharedCollection, userProfile.user);
  }

  protected loadRelationshipsOptions(): void {
    this.userService
      .query()
      .pipe(map((res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => res.body ?? []))
      .pipe(map((users: IUser[]) => this.userService.addUserToCollectionIfMissing<IUser>(users, this.userProfile?.user)))
      .subscribe((users: IUser[]) => (this.usersSharedCollection = users));
  }
}
```

---

// user.service.ts - the query() retrieves the users from the java backend API

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { ApplicationConfigService } from 'app/core/config/application-config.service';
import { createRequestOption } from 'app/core/request/request-util';
import { isPresent } from 'app/core/util/operators';
import { Pagination } from 'app/core/request/request.model';
import { IUser, getUserIdentifier } from './user.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {
  private resourceUrl = this.applicationConfigService.getEndpointFor('api/users');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private applicationConfigService: ApplicationConfigService) {}

  query(req?: Pagination): Observable<HttpResponse<IUser[]>> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get<IUser[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
  }

  compareUser(o1: Pick<IUser, 'id'> | null, o2: Pick<IUser, 'id'> | null): boolean {
    return o1 && o2 ? o1.id === o2.id : o1 === o2;
  }

  addUserToCollectionIfMissing<Type extends Partial<IUser> & Pick<IUser, 'id'>>(
    userCollection: Type[],
    ...usersToCheck: (Type | null | undefined)[]
  ): IUser[] {
    const users: Type[] = usersToCheck.filter(isPresent);
    if (users.length > 0) {
      const userCollectionIdentifiers = userCollection.map(userItem => getUserIdentifier(userItem)!);
      const usersToAdd = users.filter(userItem => {
        const userIdentifier = getUserIdentifier(userItem);
        if (userCollectionIdentifiers.includes(userIdentifier)) {
          return false;
        }
        userCollectionIdentifiers.push(userIdentifier);
        return true;
      });
      return [...usersToAdd, ...userCollection];
    }
    return userCollection;
  }
}
```

---

// PublicUserResource.java - the java API that retrieves the users, with a default 20 users in the list. It has pagination to retrieve the next set of 20 by passing the pag, size and  sort parameters in the request URL.

```
    /**
     * {@code GET /users} : get all users with only the public informations - calling this are allowed for anyone.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and with body all users.
     */
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAllPublicUsers(@org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("REST request to get all public User names");
        if (!onlyContainsAllowedProperties(pageable)) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        final Page<UserDTO> page = userService.getAllPublicUsers(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```